# Python - Category Name Web Scraping for Walmart

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get Department names from this Walmart [link](https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391). You can see that, firstly there are 7 departments on the left inside `Departments` (Chocolate cookies, cookies, butter cookies,...). When I click `See All Departments` , 9 more categories are added so now the number is 16. I'm trying to get all 16 departments with automatically. I wrote this code;

```
from selenium import webdriver

n_links = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/Desktop/demo/chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391" 
driver.get(url)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Departments']/div/div/ul").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Departments']/div/div/button/span").click()
search2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Departments']/div/div/div/div").text

sep = search.split('\n')
sep2 = search2.split('\n')

lngth = len(sep)
lngth2 = len(sep2)

for i in range (1,lngth):
    path = "//*[@id='Departments']/div/div/ul/li"+"["+ str(i) + "]/a"
    nav_links = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).get_attribute('href')
    n_links.append(nav_links)
    
for i in range (1,lngth2):
    path = "//*[@id='Departments']/div/div/div/div/ul/li"+"["+ str(i) + "]/a"
    nav_links2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).get_attribute('href')
    n_links.append(nav_links2)   
    
print(n_links)
print(len(n_links))
```

When I run the code, in the end, I can see the links inside `n_links` array. But the problem is; sometimes it has 13 links, sometimes 14. It should be 16 and I haven't seen 16 yet, only 13 or 14. I tried to add `time.sleep(3)` before `search2` line, but didn't work. Can you help me ?

Comment: It's ok to use `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: doesnt matter, we can @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated than it is. You are correct that you may need to wait to get the departments if you are clicking the button.

```
# This code will get all the departments shown
    departments = []
    departments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class,'department')]") 
 
# Click on the show all departments button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-automation-id='button']//span[contains(text(),'all Departments')]").click()

# Will get the departments shown
    departments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class,'department')]")
    
# Iterate through the departments
for d in departments:
            print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

To print all products (16), you can try searching for them using a CSS Selector instead: `.collapsible-content > ul a, .sometimes-shown a`.

In your example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = (
    "https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391"
)
driver.get(url)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Departments']/div/div/ul").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Departments']/div/div/button/span").click()

all_departments = [
    link.get_attribute("href")
    for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        ".collapsible-content > ul a, .sometimes-shown a"
    )
]

print(len(all_departments))
print(all_departments)
```

Output:

```
16
['https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/chocolate-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_4007138', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8331066', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/butter-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_7803640', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/shortbread-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8026949', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/coconut-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_6970757', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/healthy-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_7466302', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/keebler-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_3596825', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/biscotti/976759_976787_1001391_2224095', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/gluten-free-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_4362193', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/molasses-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_3338971', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/peanut-butter-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_6460174', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/pepperidge-farm-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_2410932', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/snickerdoodle-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8926167', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/sugar-free-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_5314659', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/tate-s-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_9480535', 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/vegan-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8007359']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `beautifulsoup`:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#searchContent").contents[0])

# uncomment to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


def find_departments(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if "name" in data and data["name"] == "Departments":
            yield data
        else:
            for v in data.values():
                yield from find_departments(v)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for v in data:
            yield from find_departments(v)


departments = next(find_departments(data), {})

for d in departments.get("values", []):
    print(
        "{:<30} {}".format(
            d["name"], "https://www.walmart.com" + d["baseSeoURL"]
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Chocolate Cookies              https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/chocolate-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_4007138
Cookies                        https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8331066
Butter Cookies                 https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/butter-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_7803640
Shortbread Cookies             https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/shortbread-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8026949
Coconut Cookies                https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/coconut-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_6970757
Healthy Cookies                https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/healthy-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_7466302
Keebler Cookies                https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/keebler-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_3596825
Biscotti                       https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/biscotti/976759_976787_1001391_2224095
Gluten-Free Cookies            https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/gluten-free-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_4362193
Molasses Cookies               https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/molasses-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_3338971
Peanut Butter Cookies          https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/peanut-butter-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_6460174
Pepperidge Farm Cookies        https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/pepperidge-farm-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_2410932
Snickerdoodle Cookies          https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/snickerdoodle-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8926167
Sugar-Free Cookies             https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/sugar-free-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_5314659
Tate's Cookies                 https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/tate-s-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_9480535
Vegan Cookies                  https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/vegan-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8007359
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.visibility_of_all_elements_located`?

```
texts = []
links =[]

driver.get('https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='See all Departments']/parent::button"))).click()
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.department-single-level a")))
for element in elements:
    #to get text
    texts.append(element.text)
    #to get link by attribute name
    links.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
    
print(texts)
print(links)
```

Console output:

```
[u'Chocolate Cookies', u'Cookies', u'Butter Cookies', u'Shortbread Cookies', u'Coconut Cookies', u'Healthy Cookies', u'Keebler Cookies', u'Biscotti', u'Gluten-Free Cookies', u'Molasses Cookies', u'Peanut Butter Cookies', u'Pepperidge Farm Cookies', u'Snickerdoodle Cookies', u'Sugar-Free Cookies', u"Tate's Cookies", u'Vegan Cookies']
[u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/chocolate-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_4007138', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8331066', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/butter-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_7803640', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/shortbread-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8026949', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/coconut-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_6970757', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/healthy-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_7466302', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/keebler-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_3596825', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/biscotti/976759_976787_1001391_2224095', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/gluten-free-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_4362193', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/molasses-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_3338971', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/peanut-butter-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_6460174', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/pepperidge-farm-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_2410932', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/snickerdoodle-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8926167', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/sugar-free-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_5314659', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/tate-s-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_9480535', u'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/vegan-cookies/976759_976787_1001391_8007359']
```

Need the following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```